# Cannot use CSS in GTK+ 3, using GtkCssProvider

Tags: css, c, gcc, gtk

I'm writing a text editor in C with GTK+ 3, but I've encountered an issue I have not been able to resolve. I'm trying to add a global stylesheet for the entire application, but the style won't apply.

Here is the relevant function from my program:

```
void set_window_background(Shanty *instance)
{
    GError *err;
    GFile *stylesheet = g_file_new_for_path("./style.css");
    GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_get_default();

    // Add a name in order to find widget in CSS
    gtk_widget_set_name(instance->container, "contained");

    // Load style and add to screen
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(instance->style,
                                    stylesheet, &err);

    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen
            (gdk_display_get_default_screen(display),
             GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(instance->style),
             GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

    // Check if any error has occured:
    if(err != NULL) printf("Couldn't load stylesheet.\n");
}
```

...where `instance->style` is a GtkCssProvider and `instance->container` is a GtkOverlay.

**I've tried the following things:**

- Varied the GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY flag (I tried all available flags)
- Tried referring to the application via widget, name and the global tag (*) in the CSS file
- Tried loading the provider via file and path
- Explicitly got the display/screen via the appropriate GDK function
- Printed the error onto the command line - it's not throwing one!
- Varied the widget that is affected by the styling contained within the stylesheet (I assumed that GtkOverlay maybe doesn't have some CSSProperties, but it didn't change anything)
- Tried applying the styling to a GtkGrid which is a child of the overlay, since I thought that it might be covering the parent widget.

Sadly, none of the above things did anything and I'm somewhat at a loss.
Here are the contents of my style.css file:

```
#contained {
    background-color: #1F416E;
}
```

I've also tried adding a GtkImage to the overlay and that works, but the scaling is weird to work with and I'll need CSS support definitely later on for keybindings and additional styling.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you really need that way? [Does this help](https://youtu.be/1LppFd7dTMI)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The code in my original post was partly adapted using that video (or a video from the same playlist). I definitely need CSS, because key bindings are also implemented using a stylesheet.

Comment: @millicents I'm running into the same problem with gtk3.  Any named widget is ignored in the CSS portion, or so it seems.  Time to go back to GTK2 as Gimp still uses it, so it's going nowhere fast.